# how to use Roles Interceptor in struts 2

Tags: struts2, interceptor

I'm want to make use of the **RolesInterceptor** which comes with Struts 2 in my application for authorization of users. But doesn't found any reference to implement it.

Would appreciate your kind hints.

Comment: What problem do you have with `RolesInterceptor`? Just use it like any other interceptor.

Comment: It takes allowedRoles as parameter in struts.xml but how it is going to check for roles mentioned in the parameter?

Comment: Using `request.isUserInRole` method. Or what do you mean how?

Comment: But Struts docs says that Action will only be executed if the user has the correct JAAS role. 
And request.isUserInRole checks for role in web.xml not in struts.xml.

Comment: What? Maybe see the source for `RolesInterceptor` and just try it out.